# All applications to indicator-applet?

Tags: unity, indicator, notification-area

Are all programs goining to indicator-applet in unity ubuntu 11.04 and the notification area is going to be removed completly? Like deluge, network manager and so? Now You can't remove notification area applet, because some programs use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the notification area is going to be removed in 11.04. From the [Canonical Design](http://design.canonical.com/2010/04/notification-area/) blog:

> Our roadmap is that in Ubuntu 11.04, one year from now, there will be no notification area. And in Ubuntu Netbook Edition, we’ll remove it even earlier, in 10.10. So if you develop an application that uses the notification area, and you want the millions of Ubuntu users to be able to use it, now is the time to change it.

More information on the transition is [available here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotificationAreaTransition).

Comment: Does anyone know if it actually was removed in the 10.10 Netbook edition? (when installing it 'on top' of the Desktop edition the notification area remains)

Comment: Isn't that going to cause problems, like, say; WINE and it's ilk? What about Spotify? Is there going to be a fallback method in place to turn a notification icon into an indicator applet?